# Terminator load custom configuration

Tags: linux, terminator

i am using terminator 0.96.
When I start programming I have to open my terminator do a few splits and start programms in every split. Is it possible to do this with a script?

For example splitting terminal in 4 windows and use a command in every window.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Define you layout in the "Layouts" tab of the preferences then see http://askubuntu.com/questions/158159/how-do-i-get-terminator-to-start-up-with-my-custom-layout

Comment: thanks it is possible to load the layout via command ? when i am inside a active terminator window, to change this? My problem is that i use commands which are defined in my bashrc, so when i use somethink like "top" it works well, but my commands inside the bashrc aren't working

Comment: To keep your shell alive in the terminal after your command has run, see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/473111/terminator-execute-script-and-keep-command-prompt-active

Comment: If your question is right, then @Denys already answered you. ;-) If your problem is that you want to use commands which are defined in your `bashrc` but you can't, then either you should edit the question or create a new one. I could help you with that if you changed it or created a new one! :-P

Comment: Try the proposal in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46407557/2414129

Comment: You can try using [Terminator Layout Builder](https://pypi.org/project/terminator-layout-builder/) to easily manage layout.

Answer (score 4):

You can save layouts, though some of the preferences won't save in Terminator, at least not for me.

What I did was altering the default layout in preferences (right-click > preferences) to make it save the layout of the different terminals.

Then to save custom commands, I edited the configuration file directly:
`~/.config/terminator/config`
Here you'll have to enter a 'command' line that ends with `; bash`, like so:

```
[[[terminal2]]]
  command = cd ~/Documents/myPath; bash
...
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Follow this Tutorial to set and save your layout:
   http://www.linuxnov.com/the-complete-guide-to-configure-terminator-terminal-emulator-layouts/
2. Next right-click on any split window and choose Preferences, and in the Preferences dialog, Global Tab > Behavior section, check the checkbox called "Window geometry hints".
3. Edit the ~/.config/terminator/config file. "YOUR-SAVED-LAYOUT" in the config example below refers to the name you gave to you layout after following the steps on the tutorial above. Config file looks like this before you edit:

   ```
   [global_config]
     geometry_hinting = True
     title_use_system_font = False
    [keybindings]
    [layouts]
      [[default]]
        [[[child1]]]
          parent = window0
          type = Terminal
        [[[window0]]]
          parent = ""
          type = Window
      [[YOUR-SAVED-LAYOUT]]
        [[[child0]]]
          fullscreen = False
   ...
   ...
   ```
4. Delete the "default" node above so only your layout is left. Example below:

   ```
   [global_config]
     geometry_hinting = True
     title_use_system_font = False
   [keybindings]
   [layouts]
     [[YOUR-SAVED-LAYOUT]]
       [[[child0]]]
         fullscreen = False
   ...
   ...
   ```
5. Rename "YOUR-SAVED-LAYOUT" to "default" as follows:

   ```
   [global_config]
    geometry_hinting = True
    title_use_system_font = False
   [keybindings]
   [layouts]
     [[default]]
       [[[child0]]]
         fullscreen = False
   ...
   ...
   ```
6. Save the config file and exit.
7. Close and open Terminator. Your layout should now be default layout and applied everytime you launch Terminator.

NB: There is a bug. i use version 1.90 on debian 9 and it won't launch with the panes in their right position. Close and launch again.

Comment: the link/URL to www.linuxnov.com is rotten, no longer available!