# Terminator: how to open a tab within a splitted pane

Tags: terminator

Whenever I've tried to create a new tab, it's always opened at window level. What I'm trying to achieve is to open a tab within the current active split pane I'm working in. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: It is no clear to me what a "tab within the current active split pane" would look like.  There is a companion utility command called: `remotinator   new_tab`.  That makes a new tab in the window.  (Use `remotinator   --help`).  You may split the "active pane" again with `remotinator `,  it isn't a tab so much as another sub-panel.  May be that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Terminator for the past 3-4 years, and I haven't seen what you are asking to be possible.

That being said, you may submit a feature request here:

- https://launchpad.net/terminator

and it may get implemented in a future version.

I'm not sure how much I would use that feature, but could be interesting to try it out.

Edit: I've just realized that there may be some workarounds:

- Split the pane in question, and drag one of them to be very small. And when you want to "switch tabs" then you can drag the edge again and make the other sub-pane very small. IIRC I've done this occasionally.
- Try tmux to see if it supports something like what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

1. Follow this Tutorial to set and save your layout:
   http://www.linuxnov.com/the-complete-guide-to-configure-terminator-terminal-emulator-layouts/
2. Next right-click on any split window and choose Preferences, and in the Preferences dialog, Global Tab > Behavior section, check the checkbox called "Window geometry hints".
3. Edit the ~/.config/terminator/config file. "YOUR-SAVED-LAYOUT" in the config example below refers to the name you gave to you layout after following the steps on the tutorial above. Config file looks like this before you edit:

   ```
   [global_config]
     geometry_hinting = True
     title_use_system_font = False
    [keybindings]
    [layouts]
      [[default]]
        [[[child1]]]
          parent = window0
          type = Terminal
        [[[window0]]]
          parent = ""
          type = Window
      [[YOUR-SAVED-LAYOUT]]
        [[[child0]]]
          fullscreen = False
   ...
   ...
   ```
4. Delete the "default" node above so only your layout is left. Example below:

   ```
   [global_config]
     geometry_hinting = True
     title_use_system_font = False
   [keybindings]
   [layouts]
     [[YOUR-SAVED-LAYOUT]]
       [[[child0]]]
         fullscreen = False
   ...
   ...
   ```
5. Rename "YOUR-SAVED-LAYOUT" to "default" as follows:

   ```
   [global_config]
    geometry_hinting = True
    title_use_system_font = False
   [keybindings]
   [layouts]
     [[default]]
       [[[child0]]]
         fullscreen = False
   ...
   ...
   ```
6. Save the config file and exit.
7. Close and open Terminator. Your layout should now be default layout and applied everytime you launch Terminator.

NB: There is a bug. i use version 1.90 on debian 9 and it won't launch with the panes in their right position. Close and launch again.